# Who are reputable historians who study ancient Greece?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, greece, reference

I was wanting to know reputable historians who specialize in Ancient Greek Civilization? For example, Bettany Hughes is one, but I would like to know some more.

Comment: Isn't this a reference question?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I believe that we should use this to test the idea of a community wiki answer.

Comment: @LisaSmith - could you clarify the question to indicate if you're looking for modern sources or contemporary sources?  Is Xenophon an acceptable answer?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace This is what I was confused by, it was unclear what was being asked, maybe an argument for closing it, but I think we should just include both. Is there a way to tag someone who hasn't already commented?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Based on the example I believe it refers to modern day historians. What do you think?

Comment: @Benjamin; I agree, I'm just hoping we can get OP to clarify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list answer

Comment: Please define "reputable" for us

Comment: The answer to this question could prove useful, but it needs rephrasing.

Answer (score 4):

[Thucydides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thucydides) and [Xenophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophon).

And if you can sacrifice some credibility for entertainment, [Herodotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodotus).

Also, not historians but I really recommend reading Homer, Hesiod, Aeschylus,  Sophocles and Euripides to get a grasp of their world.

Modern historians specialized in Ancient Greece I've only read [Donald Kagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Kagan) and [Luciano Canfora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciano_Canfora).

EDIT:

Wikipedia Category [Scholars of ancient Greek history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scholars_of_ancient_Greek_history) has 43 names of modern historians in it.

Comment: Since this is a reference list question, you might want to turn it into a community wiki.

Comment: Loosely concur with @Benjamin, although I would suggest creating a community wiki answer that contains the the first two. I would like to see some voting and discussion before we add Kagan and Canfora.

Comment: I agree, but someone with more priviledges than me might be required to "wikify" this.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Because of his historical importance, I think we should leave Herodotus as well, with a notation that due to his methods, reliability is often in question.

Comment: @Brasidas Someone could also just post a new answer that is a wiki.

Comment: The question was probably about modern historians.

Comment: I agree with @Alex, the OP uses present tense in the question.